# Using ImportXML to pull HTML tags along with data

Tags: google-sheets, importxml

Can ImportXML be used to pull the HTML tags along with the data?

For example:

```
importxml(A1,"//div[@id='qlist-wrapper']") on stackoverflow.com
```

will pull all the data in the div with the id `qlist-wrapper` in an imploded format.

Is there a way where I can pull the data along with the relevant `<div>`s and `<li>`s and `<ul>`s ?

Strange request, I understand, but I have a need in one place and anyway of pulling the tags along with the data together will be really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

SO it turns out you can do this after all!

```
=importxml("http://stackoverflow.com","//div[@id='qlist-wrapper']//@*")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, `=importXML` does not offer this kind of XML formatting. But you can use a [script](https://www.google.com/script/start/) to get parts of a page with HTML tags, like this:

```
function getHtml() {
  var text = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://webapps.stackexchange.com").getContentText();
  var div = text.match(/<div id="qlist-wrapper">[\s\S]*(?=<div>\s*<a id="home-browse")/)[0];
  var qlist = XmlService.parse(div);
  var root = qlist.getRootElement();
  var list = root.getChild('div');
  var children = list.getChildren();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    sheet.getRange(i+1, 1).setValue(XmlService.getPrettyFormat().format(children[i]));
  }
}
```

#### Explanation

The first line fetches the HTML source of the page. Sometimes one can parse it with `XmlService.parse`, but for complex pages with scripts, etc, this usually fails. For this reason, I use a regular expression to extract only a fragment, and then parse that. After parsing, one can do whatever [XmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/xml-service) offers: I just get a list of questions, and put them in separate cells in a readable XML format. One can, of course, drill deeper and extract particular XML elements from here.

An important caveat is that Google crawler is an anonymous visitor to the site: it gets served the page for anonymous users, which is not the same as you see.

```
<div class="question-summary narrow" id="question-summary-91365">
  <div onclick="window.location.href='/questions/91365/filtering-by-case-sensitive-string-equality'" class="cp">
    <div class="votes">
      <div class="mini-counts">
        <span title="2 votes">2</span>
      </div>
      <div>votes</div>
    </div>
    <div class="status answered-accepted" title="one of the answers was accepted as the correct answer">
      <div class="mini-counts">
        <span title="2 answers">2</span>
      </div>
      <div>answers</div>
    </div>
    <div class="views">
      <div class="mini-counts">
        <span title="41 views">41</span>
      </div>
      <div>views</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="summary">
    <h3>
      <a href="/questions/91365/filtering-by-case-sensitive-string-equality" class="question-hyperlink" title="I discovered (when answering this question) that string comparison in filter is case insensitive: the formulas =filter(A:A, B:B = &quot;Yes&quot;) and =filter(A:A, B:B = &quot;YES&quot;) have the same output.   ...">Filtering by case-sensitive string equality</a>
    </h3>
    <div class="tags t-google-spreadsheets">
      <a href="/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheets" class="post-tag" title="show questions tagged 'google-spreadsheets'" rel="tag">google-spreadsheets</a>
    </div>
    <div class="started">
      <a href="/questions/91365/filtering-by-case-sensitive-string-equality/?lastactivity" class="started-link">
        modified
        <span title="2016-03-30 19:42:07Z" class="relativetime">54 mins ago</span>
      </a>
      <a href="/users/79865/404">404</a>
      <span class="reputation-score" title="reputation score 11872" dir="ltr">11.9k</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```